# C++: Equivalent to use namespace for class definitions?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, scope

So, I am looking to make my code cleaner. Here is what I have:

obj.hpp

```
class obj {
    obj();

    int return0();
};
```

obj.cpp

```
using namespace obj; //illegal!!
obj() { }

int return0()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I think that writing `obj::return0()...` is a bit redundant. This becomes trickier when I have sub-classes, where I do things like `obj::child::child2::return0()...`

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590/how-do-you-properly-use-namespaces-in-c

This?

Comment: There's no way to do this in C++.

Comment: You shouldn't normally have a nested class in a nested class in a class. You could use a typedef, though.

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly you can just write the method implemtation in the header file. It's perfectly fine fo do so, if it was something like a template you would in fact HAVE to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to avoid repeating the class name in the implementation file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887211/is-it-possible-to-avoid-repeating-the-class-name-in-the-implementation-file)

Comment: @Patrick This is not necessarily fine. You can get in horrible ODR cases with this approach.

Comment: @RobKennedy Cool that is a duplicate of my question. I just wasn't able to find it through web searches >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using namespace x` lets you `call` functions in x, not `define` them.

As a comment pointed out, you can inline the function in the header file if it's short.

obj.hpp

```
class obj {
    obj(){}
    int return0(){return 0;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess there is no alternative unless I want to inline everything!